# Is there a way to have gmail accounts viewed like Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

Is the best app that makes email Gmail look like Outlook?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outlook- just set it up to check the messages with imap ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can run your gmail account FROM Outlook. I have been running Hotmail that way for over a year and am just starting to follow the direction for gmail.
This will get you there: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=12103

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can use an email client of your choise to access your GMail account, in which case you can fit it to your liking, yes, but you cannot change the web interface.

Comment: oh, i dunno, a little application of *grease*, a little *monkey* ing around...

Comment: That's not changing the web interface. That's downloading it, then opening it up, and rewriting it. You can photograph a car, then change its color on the photo in Photoshop, but the car's colour is still what it was.

Comment: But yes, I see your point. Unfortunatelly (or luckily) even with gm it won't resemble Outlook, not by far ...

Comment: you're right, of course. it's a change, but local only.  less akin to changing one photo, more akin to rewiring your brain so when *you* see that car it looks red instead of the blue it appears to everyone else.